# TestNG - Get @Factory parameters supplied to constructor in test listener

Tags: java, groovy, testng

Given the following test class:

```
@Listeners([FactoryLogger.class])
class DataProviderOnFactoryTest {
    private String s;
    private int i;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "data")
    DataProviderOnFactoryTest(String test, Integer i) {
        this.test = test
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] data() {
        return [["Value 1", 1], ["Value 2", 2]]
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // A test!
    }
}
```

How do I get the values that were passed into the constructor using the @Factory into the test listener?

```
class FactoryLogger extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onTestFailure(tr)

        //TODO: Need values that were passed into the constructor!
        println(tr.getTestName() + 
            ": failed when test class was provided parameters [" 
                + _____ + ", " + _____ + "]")        
    }
}
```

I've gone through the ITestResult object which contains getParameters() but that only works if the @DataProvider is on the test method. I also can't use reflection to get the fields as the test class may have many variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem and what follows is my solution. In my case it was enough to just dump the parameters into sysout in order to see for which params the test methods failed. If you need to have the parameters at hand after testing, you can (hopefully :) ) extend this solution easily enough.

So, here we go...

Wrap your parameters into some composite and make sure you override the `toString()` method:

```
public interface CommonTestParameter {

    String getStuff();
    Object getMoreStuff();
}

public class TestParameterImpl implements CommonTestParameter {

    private final String stuff;
    private final Object moreStuff;

    public TestParameterImpl(String aStuff, Object aMoreStuff){
        this.stuff = aStuff;
        this.moreStuff = aMoreStuff;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStuff(){
        return this.stuff;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getMoreStuff(){
        return this.moreStuff;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "stuff = \"" + this.stuff + "\", moreStuff = \"" + this.moreStuff.toString() + "\"";
    }
}
```

Create an abstract parent for your test classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractTestParent implements ITest {

    private String testName = "";

    // This method actually is what provides you with the functionality of renaming 
    // your tests for the standard testNG logger
    @Override 
    public String getTestName(){
        return this.testName;
    }

    protected abstract CommonTestParameter getTestParameter();    

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method aMethod) {
        this.testName = aMethod.getName() + "[" + getTestParameter().toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

And finally create the test class:

```
public class TestClassImpl extends CommonTestParent {

    private CommonTestParameter testParam;

    @Override
    protected CommonTestParameter getTestParameter(){
        return this.testParam;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "awesomeDataProvider")
    public static Iterator<Object[]> provideData(){
        List<Object[]> dataList = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
        dataList.add(new TestParameterImpl("Stuff1!", "More stuff1!"));
        dataList.add(new TestParameterImpl("Stuff2!", "More stuff2!"));
        return dataList.iterator();
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "awesomeDataProvider")
    public TestClassImpl(CommonTestParameter aTestParam){
        this.testParam = aTestParam;
    }

    @Test
    public void testStuff(){
        System.out.println(this.testParam.getStuff());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMoreStuff(){
        System.out.println(this.testParam.getMoreStuff().toString());
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you run these tests, instead of console output in the standard format of

```
PASSED: testStuff
PASSED: testStuff
PASSED: testMoreStuff
PASSED: testMoreStuff
```

you will actually see what arguments you have called the test method with in the format you have specified via overriding the `toString()` method.

```
PASSED: testStuff[stuff = "Stuff1!", moreStuff = "More stuff1!"]
PASSED: testStuff[stuff = "Stuff2!", moreStuff = "More stuff!"]
PASSED: testMoreStuff[stuff = "Stuff1!", moreStuff = "More stuff1!"]
PASSED: testMoreStuff[stuff = "Stuff2!", moreStuff = "More stuff2!"]
```

If you actually need to process the parameters further, you can iterate upon this concept and store them into a `Map<String, List<CommonTestParameter>>` (where the key represents a method name and the value represents all parameters you called the method with) and then parse it in some `@AfterSuite` method.

Hope this helps, Janek.

Comment: The solution works, but I really think we need a way to do this outside of using a parent class. It's the whole reason we have Listeners in the first place. Thanks for the help, I'll use it until I find a Listener solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of any use! :)

Answer (score -1):

Make `class FactoryLogger` abstract, and have an abstract function `getTestParams()`.  Then each of your classes that extend `FactoryLogger` will have to store the params and pass them in `getTestParams()`.

Comment: Nothing will extend FactoryLogger as it's being called within the @Listener annotation. So converting it to abstract and adding functions will not solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the problem right.  I can't help you then, sorry.